# Why am I getting a file not found error when reading a pdf file on jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, import, operating-system, pypdf

I'm trying to open a file in Jupyter notebook (first time using after only using atom).  I'm getting an error that it can't read the file path.  I'm sure the file path is correct, though.  Your help is appreciated.  I tried the regular open method and open with os.

```
import PyPDF2
import os
path = "M:\2020\BD NY\Month End\01 - Jan 2020\Pershing - LBG\01.31.2020 - LBG - AVERAGE PRICE.pdf"
os.startfile(path)
pdfFileObj = open(path)
```

And my error:

---

> FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in 
>         2 import os
>         3 path = "M:\2020\BD NY\Month End\01 - Jan 2020\Pershing - LBG\01.31.2020 - LBG - AVERAGE PRICE.pdf"
>   ----> 4 os.startfile(path)
>         5 pdfFileObj = open(path)
>
> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'M:\x820\BD NY\Month End\x01 - Jan 2020\Pershing - LBG\x01.31.2020 - LBG - AVERAGE PRICE.pdf'

Comment: Could you try doubling up each backslash as \\ . In a string, \ is an escape character so perhaps one of them has produced a different character than you intended? Does it work in Atom?

Comment: Shouldn't you use a path like this `E:/some/path` or `E:\\some\\path`?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this on Windows or Linux? If you're on Windows,then you should be use a path like (using `\\`)

```
C:\\Users\\apple\\Downloads\train.csv
```

A simple way is to move your files to be read under the same folder of your python file, then you just need to use the name of the file, without calling another path.

Comment: I'm using a windows.  I copied the file path and added the name of the file.pdf.  I noticed on the error it said cannot find the file specified and gives me a file name different than the one I specified.

Comment: Look into what absolute file paths are and use that for your file.

Comment: Yes, using \\ instead of \ solved the issue.  I tried to give your answer plus 1 to close it out but don’t have the reputation points for that yet.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: If this answer helped in your problem, please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more information